# Unit testing DynamoDB SDK in Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, testing

I'm using the AWS SDK in Go, but I'm having trouble unit testing my DynamoDB updates. Basically, I'm using `gomock` to set the expected `UpdateItemInput` like so:

```
return m.EXPECT().UpdateItemWithContext(
            gomock.Any(),
            &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput {
                ConditionExpression: aws.String("(#0 = :0) AND (#1 = :1)"),
                ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
                    "#0": aws.String("PK"),
                    "#1": aws.String("SK"),
                    "#2": aws.String("SomeAttrName"),
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue {
                    ":0": {S: aws.String(primaryKey)},
                    ":1": {S: aws.String(secondaryKey)},
                    ":2": {S: aws.String(ValueToUpdate)},
                },
                Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    "PK": {S: aws.String(primaryKey)},
                    "SK": {S: aws.String(secondaryKey)},
                },
                ReturnValues:     aws.String(dynamodb.ReturnValueAllNew),
                TableName:        aws.String(dynamo.TableName),
                UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET #2 = :2\n"),
            }
```

However, when I run the test, it fails because it seems there is a mismatch between what gomock expected and what it got. The positions of the values in the `UpdateItemInput` from the business logic are different every time I run the test, which I think is what's messing this up.

Is there a better way to test things like this in Go? Or if not, is there a way to enforce the same order every time, or ignore the order?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example GO unit test here in Github:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/gov2/dynamodb/ScanItems